# CustomTick Label Location

Tags: lightningchart

I've been working with custom ticks recently and have been testing out different configrations based on this example:
https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0011-customTicksScrolling.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light

Is it possible to move the label that's created with each custom tick away from the xAxis? I'm hoping to move it to a point inside the chart at a specific point. Below is a screenshot that shows the custom tick label appearing on the xAxis and a second arrow towards the top where I'd like it to appear. I'm hoping there's a way to do this using the .setMarker method.

[image]

Thoughts?

Edit:
This is what I'm looking for the chart to look like. The bottom of the chart would be seamless with no padding or room for marker text.
[image]

Comment: This can definitely be done but perhaps not with just a custom tick. You can also place any ui elements, like text boxes on axis and position them anywhere within the charting area using axis coordinates, causing them to move along as the axis scrolls.

Comment: It would help to have a visual reference of the second "arrow towards the top" to provide a clearer example.

Comment: Thanks Niilo. I added a second picture to the original post to show what I'm looking to do. The goal is to have several charts stacked on top of each other to save on real estate. I found that when I added a custom tick, it would add an xAxis section for the marker text to appear, even with this setting xAxis.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Empty). 

So, my thought was to move that marker up into the chart instead of down there as I was going to add markers like that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to hide the label on the xAxis using .setAllocatesAxisSpace(false). From there, I just generated a new marker on the chart at the appropriate location.